# javascript getting function undefined error

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am getting the error `stripecall is not defined` even though function is defined and it is a global function:

Here is the code:

```
<button type="button" id="addcard" class="btn btn-success" 
     onclick="stripecall();">
    <i class="icon-save"></i> Submit
</button>
```

And function is defined like:

```
function stripecall() {
  // function stuff
}
```

### What I've tried:

- Tried enclusing whole form in `<form></form>` tags
- Tried binding button click event via jQuery's `click`, `live` and `on`

Everything seems to be okay but still getting that `func is not defined` error.

Can someone help me what I am missing ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You have multiple syntax errors in your JS, check that first with some debugger. `isCreditCard` function: `else: mu --;` should be `else: muu--;`. Also in `stripeResponseHandler` function at the end you have a doublequote left open.

Comment: First check your JS for errors then submit to SO.

Comment: @Fracsi: Thanks man you are so quick alone doublq quote was the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function stripecall is never defined because you have a syntax error line 1425

```
else {
    alert(msg);
    $('.btn-success').css("display", "");
    $('#loading').css("display", "none");
}
//location.href = "editcontact/index/
"; // <--- this is the problem
});
```

Comment: True that was the issue, @Fracsi already pointed that out but I will accept this as answer :) Thanks